# SQL Server if bit parameter = 0 return records where field has value of 0 or null

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, resultset

I have a large stored procedure (500+ lines) from which Carrier records are returned. One of the parameters that I pass a value to when calling this stored procedure is to be used in a where clause to filter the result set. This is a bit type parameter, represented by a boolean property in my entity model (Web API).

I cannot figure out how to construct the where clause to return the appropriate records in the result set.

This is the basic outline of what I want to happen:

1. If the bit type parameter is `NULL` return all records
2. If the bit type parameter equals `1` return all records where the specified bit type field has a value of `1`
3. If the bit type parameter equals `0` return all records where the specified bit type field is null or has a value of `0`

My attempts, out of context (please excuse, I'm not a strong SQL developer):

```
DECLARE @Intrastate bit;
SET @Intrastate = 0; --should return all records where Intrastate field
                     --is null or has a value of 0
SELECT * FROM Carriers c
    WHERE @Intrastate IS NULL
        OR c.Intrastate = CASE WHEN @Intrastate = 1 THEN @Intrastate END
        OR c.Intrastate = CASE WHEN @Intrastate = 0 THEN @Intrastate END
        OR c.Intrastate = NULLIF(@Intrastate, 0)
```

The above query only returns records with Intrastate field having a value of 0, excludes records with Intrastate field as null.

```
DECLARE @Intrastate bit;
SET @Intrastate = 0; --should return all records where Intrastate field
                     --is null or has a value of 0
SELECT * FROM Carriers c
    WHERE @Intrastate IS NULL
        OR c.Intrastate = CASE WHEN @Intrastate = 1 THEN @Intrastate END
        OR c.Intrastate in (SELECT DISTINCT Intrastate FROM Carriers
                                WHERE Intrastate = 0
                                    OR Intrastate IS NULL)
```

Again, the above query only returns records with Intrastate field having a value of 0, excludes records with Intrastate as null.

Assigning `NULL` or `1` to the `@Intrastate` parameter produces the desired result sets, as defined above.

My issue is only with the result set return when the `@Intrastate` parameter has a value of `0`.

Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this solution looks like it is a lot of typing but if you have a [function on the predicate column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) in the WHERE clause, sql server most likely going to scan the whole table and not going to use your indexes:

```
SELECT * FROM Carriers c
WHERE @Intrastate IS NULL
      OR (@Intrastate = 1 AND c.Intrastate = 1)
      OR ( @Intrastate = 0 AND (  c.Intrastate IS NULL 
                                  OR c.Intrastate = 0 ))
```

Comment: This solution works great. It's very clear and concise, and I appreciate the information regarding SARGability, as this factors into my query since SARGability has been maintained throughout the updates made on the stored procedure I'm working on. Thanks a pantload, Chet!

Answer (score 4):

What about...

```
...
WHERE @Intrastate IS NULL
OR ISNULL(c.Intrastate, 0) = @Intrastate
```

That way if the variable is null, you get all records and if not, you coalesce the column to 0 if null and that should cover 1=1 and 0=0/null=0.

Comment: Thanks very much! This solution works great. The only reason I didn't mark it as the accepted answer is because it's a non-SARGable query, and SARGability has to be maintained within the stored procedure I'm updating. If SARGability isn't a concern, though, this definitely works.Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

This works if you SET ANSI_NULLS Off

```
SET ANSI_NULLS Off
GO
WHERE Intrastate in (isnull(@Intrastate,Intrastate), nullif(isnull(@Intrastate,0), 0))
```

Comment: Won't work the way expected in the OP, if `Intrastate` is null.

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate? I think isnull(@Intrastate,Intrastate) will take care of that..

Comment: `x IN (a, b)` is equivalent to `x = a OR x = b`. And `x = NULL` is "false" (technically it's `NULL`, so not true), even if `x` is `NULL`. So that `WHERE` clause of yours won't ever select a record, when `Intrastate` is null, regardless of the expressions in the parenthesis to the `IN`.

Comment: my ansi_nulls are set to off.. So statement indeed works.. I've updated the answer with a mention about that..

Comment: OK, in that special case forget my comment.

Comment: However a note from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on the use of that feature: "**Important** In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature."